# Allowable triangulation

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds

I am reading *3-Manifolds* by Hempel.

Corollary 1.9 at page 8, says that if $(T,h)$ is an allowable triangulation of a pl $n$-manifold $M$ and $L$ is a subcomplex of $T$ which collapses to a vertex, then any regular neighborhood of $h(L)$ in $M$ is a pl cell.

What is  exactly an "allowable triangulation"? I cannot find a definition in the book.

Comment: I believe it just means that the charts are piecewise linear maps with that triangulation. For example, if I choose an exotic PL $\mathbb{R}^4$ the usual triangulation will not be allowable.

Comment: For smooth manifolds the analogy would be a smooth handle decomposition; this is opposed to an arbitrary handle decomposition that is not necessarily smooth.